# Remove a delegate from an event

Tags: c#, events, reflection, delegates

I have an event as follows:

```
public event EventHandler<CustomEventArgs> RaiseCustomEvent;
```

Here is some code to remove a delegate from the above event that I have working:

```
public void RemoveDelegate(Delegate del)
{
    RaiseCustomEvent -= (EventHandler<CustomEventArgs>)del;
}
```

Here is some code that I have written to remove a delegate where I know the event name:

```
public void RemoveRaiseCustomEventDelegate(Delegate del, string eventName)
{
    var field = this.GetType().GetField(eventName, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetField);

    var fieldValue = field.GetValue(this) as EventHandler<CustomEventArgs>;
    fieldValue -= (EventHandler<CustomEventArgs>)del;
}
```

In the above code, the `fieldValue` is set to null, however, when the event is raised, there is still a subscriber.

Can I please have some help to remove a delegate from an event, where I only have the event name?

Comment: when is `fieldValue` set to null? When it is assigned or when `del` is unsubscribed?

Comment: When del is unsubscribed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void RemoveRaiseCustomEventDelegate(Delegate del, string eventName)
{
    this.GetType()
        .GetEvent(eventName)
        .RemoveEventHandler(this, del);
}
```

MSDN on [GetEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wh463yz3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

MSDN on [EventInfo.RemoveEventHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.eventinfo.removeeventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: To enhance the qualtity of this answer it would be nice if you add a few lines of explanations.

Comment: GetEvent - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wh463yz3(v=vs.110).aspx                                                                            RemoveEventHandler - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.eventinfo.removeeventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I have added (and corrected) your links to the answer. Comments are second class citizens on SO; it is the answers (and questions) which should be improved to enhance the value of SO as an archive.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see `RaiseCustomEvent` will not be found in `RemoveRaiseCustomEventDelegate`. It is declared `public` and you are filtering `BindingFlags.NonPublic`.

Therefore

```
var fieldValue = field.GetValue(this) as EventHandler<CustomEventArgs>;
```

should fail. Maybe `RemoveRaiseCustomEventDelegate` is in a `catch`-block?

Comment: The code does not fail. Both the field and fieldValue variables have a value that are not null. After del is unsubscribed, the fieldValue is set to null.